# × TypeError: Object(...) is not a function, while creating store using redux and firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux, redux-firestore

These are the versions I am using :

```
 "redux": "^4.0.5",
 "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
 "redux-firestore": "^0.13.0"
 "firebase": "^7.14.3",
 "redux": "^4.0.5",
 "react-redux-firebase": "^3.4.0",
```

I am getting this error while creating the store :

```
  const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    reactReduxFirebase(firebase),
    window.__REDUX__DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
      window.__REDUX__DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this?

```
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux'
import { reducers } from 'redux/reducers'

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose

export const store = createStore(reducers, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware()))
```

you don't want to `compose` the redux dev tools. you should be doing one or the other

Comment: @SaaranshMenon what does this line do `reactReduxFirebase(firebase)` ?

Comment: found out the problem reactReduxFirebase() has been dropped in the 3.x versions.

Comment: have you fixed your issue then?

Comment: Yes the error is gone but I dont know how to connect firebase with redux and react in the new version.

Comment: I haven't seen that package before `react-redux-firebase`. I don't use it and my app integrates completely fine. I think you should just import your firebase config wherever you need to use it

Comment: let me know if you need any more help :) or if this question is closed can you accept the answer :)